# How do I make my Player Controls work when its Animation Track is playing?

Tags: unity-game-engine, timeline

I am making a railroad shooter game and I have used a timeline to make an animation. I have also written a script to move the player ship left and right while the animation is happening, but for some reason when I hit play the animation track completes and then the player controls get activated. How can I keep the controls activated at all times?

Thanks in advance. Appreciate any help in this regard.

I added player controls and I want to be able to move the player ship while animation track is playing. I am only able to move the ship after the animation track completes.
This is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float controlSpeed = 10f;

    void Update()
    {
        float yThrow = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float xThrow = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        float xOffset = xThrow * Time.deltaTime * controlSpeed;
        float newXPos = transform.localPosition.x + xOffset;

        transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (newXPos,transform.localPosition.y,transform.localPosition.z);
        Debug.Log("Test");
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjjmA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the animation inside Unity and used the gameobject's position in your Animation frames, then you will not be able to control it using the script. The animation will try to push it to the position in the animation frame.

Comment: Thank you for the response Vionix.  I am just learning Unity now from an udemy course and followed the instructions.  Can you help me fix this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are too many factors to know before I can help you. It will best, if you ask the instructor of the Udemy course. In general, if you want the gameobject to move then don't use animation to change the position.